# SwiftUI NavigationStack inside NavigationSplitView not working on iPhone and iPad

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-navigationsplitview, swiftui-navigationstack

I'm trying to use `NavigationStack` inside `NavigationSplitView`.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var mainMenu: MenuItem?
    @State var subMenu: SubMenuItem?
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView {
            List(MenuItem.allCases, selection: $mainMenu) { item in
                NavigationLink(value: item) {
                    Text(item.rawValue)
                }
            }
        } detail: {
            NavigationStack {
                List(SubMenuItem.allCases, selection: $subMenu) { item in
                    NavigationLink(value: item) {
                        Text(item.rawValue)
                    }
                }
                .navigationDestination(for: SubMenuItem.self) { selected in
                    DetailView(item: selected)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct DetailView: View {
    let item: SubMenuItem
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(item.id)
    }
}
```

On the Mac, I'm able to navigate well into the `DetailView`

[image]

But on iPhone and iPad, I'm unable to navigate to `DetailView`. I'm stuck on `SubMenu`.

[image]

[image]

Is this a known bug? or is there something wrong with my code?

*P.S. I found this question almost similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73038254/swiftui-nested-links-within-navigationstack-inside-a-navigationsplitview-not-w), but I'm NOT using multiple/nested `.navigationDestination` and my problem occurs on iPhone/iPad, not on Mac.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally figured it out. I used the `NavigationStack` with `path`, and manually set the `path` for every `subMenu` change. Now the code works on every platform.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var mainMenu: MenuItem?
    @State var subMenu: SubMenuItem?
    @State var path: [SubMenuItem] = []
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView {
            List(MenuItem.allCases, selection: $mainMenu) { item in
                NavigationLink(value: item) {
                    Text(item.rawValue)
                }
            }
            .onChange(of: mainMenu) { _ in
                // Reset subMenu selection (optional)
                subMenu = nil
            }
        } detail: {
            NavigationStack(path: $path) {
                List(SubMenuItem.allCases, selection: $subMenu) { item in
                    NavigationLink(value: item) {
                        Text(item.rawValue)
                    }
                }
                .navigationDestination(for: SubMenuItem.self) { selected in
                    DetailView(item: selected)
                }
                .onChange(of: subMenu) { sm in
                    // Manually set the path
                    if let sm {
                        path = [sm]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works, however, where I embed a NavigationStack inside a NavigationSplitView, I get the following message in the console `Update NavigationRequestObserver tried to update multiple times per frame.`
BTW this is on Xcode 14.2.

Comment: I am getting the same "Update NavigationRequestObserver tried to update multiple times per frame" when using this approach.  Did you find a fix for this or the proper way to do this?